# Replace the string with correct word in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace, spell-checking

This is my string, for which I have split the string to words

**data** is the collection of correct words

**sentence** is the string which contains some incorrect words which needs to be replaced with the corrected once

```
data="blue whale","red rose","city of joy","dream pride","rain drops","ten house","think twice"
data=[words for segments in data for words in segments.split()]

sentence = ["I'll have to thnik twycee before going to ceety of joiy along with red rossy"]
sentence = sentence.split()
```

now I'm trying to spell check

```
 def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
    WORDS = Counter(data)

    def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
        "Probability of `word`."
        return WORDS[word] / N

    def correction(word): 
        "Most probable spelling correction for word."
        return max(candidates(word), key=P)

    def candidates(word): 
        "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
        return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

    def known(words): 
        "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
        return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

    def edits1(word):
        "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
        letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
        deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
        transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
        replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
        inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
        return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

    def edits2(word): 
        "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
        return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))
```

Now what I want to do is that I want to replace all the incorrect words with the corrected words and update in the object **sentence**

> correction('thnik')
>
> O/P
>
> think

**code for updating the object "sentence"**

```
for i  in sentence:
        sentence = correction(i)
        sentence = [sentence.append(i)]
        print(sentence)
```

as the program would check for all given words and would output the result, I would join them all using `sentence = ' '.join(sentence)`
but the for loop code gives my error `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"`, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `sentence = [correction(w) for w in sentence]` ?

Comment: @khelwood your code worked fine with me ...saved my day....thanks a ton!!!

Comment: The code in the question appears to be from or based on [Peter Norvig's](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = "Thsi is my cdoe"   #Lets assume this is your sentence.    
formatted_sentence = ''
for i  in sentence:
    corrected_word = correction(i) # if "Thsi" is passed to correction it should return "This" 
    formatted_sentence += ' '.join(corrected_word)
print(formatted_sentence)
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this or you want to replace the same sentence.

Comment: You need a line `formatted_sentence = ''` at the beginning.

Comment: @Keval your code gives output as "I ' l l
I ' l lw h a l e
I ' l lw h a l et e n
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n k
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c e
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r e
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r eg o i n g
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r eg o i n gt e n
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r eg o i n gt e nc i t y
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r eg o i n gt e nc i t yo f
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w i c eb e f o r eg o i n gt e nc i t yo fj o y
I ' l lw h a l et e nt h i n kt w

Comment: can you please show what's your actual sentence and what correction returns

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.